# uwp system media transport controls reocrd button does not appear

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am developing simple uwp application for playing audion on background task. I would like to have a "record button" on lock screen. I have changed source code from sample application "BackgroundApplication" and enabled "Reord button"

```
smtc = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls;
smtc.IsEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPauseEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPlayEnabled = true;
smtc.IsNextEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPreviousEnabled = true;

smtc.IsRecordEnabled = true;
```

But no luck, there is no "Record button": 
[record button issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l91oJ.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l91oJ.png)

I will apprichiate any help on this topic.

Comment: Have you enabled Microphone in Capabilities?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. In fact, not only "Record button" does not appear. Same relevant for IsFastForwardEnabled, IsRewindEnabled and IsStopEnabled.